# Adapt web-scraper JavaScript code for Puppeteer

Tags: javascript

I have minimal coding knowledge and I'm trying to adapt some tutorials without success.

The JavaScript code I wish to adapt (script A) is pasted into the Chrome developer console and successfully pulls the data I need. This JavaScript snippet identifies the largest price graphic in an e-commerce site.

A second tutorial (script B) is run from the shell and calls the Puppeteer library. This script pulls some hotel booking data and runs successfully.

I wish to adapt script A to run from the shell using the Puppeteer library.

This is Script A -

```
let elements = [
 ...document.querySelectorAll(' body *')
]

function createRecordFromElement(element) {
 const text = element.textContent.trim()
 var record = {}
 const bBox = element.getBoundingClientRect()

if(text.length <= 30 && !(bBox.x == 0 && bBox.y == 0)) {
 record['fontSize'] = parseInt(getComputedStyle(element)['fontSize']) } 
 record['y'] = bBox.y 
 record['x'] = bBox.x 
 record['text'] = text 
 return record 
} 
let records = elements.map(createRecordFromElement) 

function canBePrice(record) { 
 if( record['y'] > 600 ||
  record['fontSize'] == undefined ||
  !record['text'].match(/(^(US ){0,1}(rs\.|Rs\.|RS\.|\$|₹|INR|USD|CAD|C\$){0,1}(\s){0,1}[\d,]+(\.\d+){0,1}(\s){0,1}(AED){0,1}$)/)
)
 return false
 else return true
}

let possiblePriceRecords = records.filter(canBePrice)
let priceRecordsSortedByFontSize = possiblePriceRecords.sort(function(a, b) {
if (a['fontSize'] == b['fontSize']) return a['y'] > b['y']
return a['fontSize'] < b['fontSize']

})
console.log(priceRecordsSortedByFontSize[0]['text']);console.log(priceRecordsSortedByFontSize[1]['text']);
```

This is Script B -

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let bookingUrl = 'insert booking URL';
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 926 });
    await page.goto(bookingUrl);

    // get hotel details
    let hotelData = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let hotels = [];
        // get the hotel elements
        let hotelsElms = document.querySelectorAll('div.sr_property_block[data-hotelid]');
        // get the hotel data
        hotelsElms.forEach((hotelelement) => {
            let hotelJson = {};
            try {
                hotelJson.name = hotelelement.querySelector('span.sr-hotel__name').innerText;
                hotelJson.reviews = hotelelement.querySelector('span.review-score-widget__subtext').innerText;
                hotelJson.rating = hotelelement.querySelector('span.review-score-badge').innerText;
                if(hotelelement.querySelector('strong.price')){
                    hotelJson.price = hotelelement.querySelector('strong.price').innerText;
                }
            }
            catch (exception){

            }
            hotels.push(hotelJson);
        });
        return hotels;
    });

    console.dir(hotelData);
})();
```

I've had various attempts at adapting Script A into the format of Script B. Various and many different errors have been thrown. Without coding knowledge, I'm not getting anywhere.

Here's one of many variations I've tried, called Script C -

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

let bookingUrl = 'https://shop.coles.com.au/a/dianella/product/moccona-coffee-capsules-espresso-7';
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
        headless: true
        });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 926 });
    await page.goto(bookingUrl);

    // get hotel details
    let hotelData = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let hotels = [];
        // get the hotel elements
        let elements = [
 ...document.querySelectorAll(' body *')
]

function createRecordFromElement(element) {
 const text = element.textContent.trim()
 var record = {}
 const bBox = element.getBoundingClientRect()

if(text.length <= 30 && !(bBox.x == 0 && bBox.y == 0)) {
 record['fontSize'] = parseInt(getComputedStyle(element)['fontSize']) } 
 record['y'] = bBox.y 
 record['x'] = bBox.x 
 record['text'] = text 
 return record 
} 
let records = elements.map(createRecordFromElement) 

function canBePrice(record) { 
 if( record['y'] > 600 ||
  record['fontSize'] == undefined ||
  !record['text'].match(/(^(US ){0,1}(rs\.|Rs\.|RS\.|\$|₹|INR|USD|CAD|C\$){0,1}(\s){0,1}[\d,]+(\.\d+){0,1}(\s){0,1}(AED){0,1}$)/)
)
 return false
 else return true
}

let possiblePriceRecords = records.filter(canBePrice)
let priceRecordsSortedByFontSize = possiblePriceRecords.sort(function(a, b) {
if (a['fontSize'] == b['fontSize']) return a['y'] > b['y']
return a['fontSize'] < b['fontSize']

})
console.log(priceRecordsSortedByFontSize[0]['text']);
})();
```

Here's the links to the tutorials for info -

https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-scrape-prices-from-any-ecommerce-website/

https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-build-a-web-scraper-using-puppeteer-and-node-js/

Is there anything obviously wrong in Script C?

Answer (score 1):

After reading through script C, it appears that you have not made any mistakes, rather the website you are attempting to access has decided to block scraper bots.

A quick host lookup on the domain shows that they are using security service section.io to block scraper bots on their website. See:

`shop.coles.com.au is an alias for shop.coles.com.au.c.section.io.`
`shop.coles.com.au.c.section.io is an alias for shop.coles.com.au.x.section.io`

Comment: Thanks for looking at the code. I didn't anticipate they would block bots!